# Ajax get jsonp gives error code 500 "request blocked" from MVC application

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jsonp

I'm writing an MVC application and I need to access some service through jsonp with an ajax call.

However, when I run my code in Visual Studio (IIS Express) then I always get back a status code 500 "request blocked", unfortunatly fiddler does not see that request so I don't have more information about the error, only the networking tab in IE/chrome's developer tools works.

When I do the request, in the networking tab I see the 500, I copy the request url, paste it in my browser, et voila, it works, I get a response.

Now I have created a JSFiddle that looks almost exactly the same as the code I'm using (only instead of inline scripts, I have it in separate files), surprise, the JSFiddle works:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
init: function(element, params) {
    $(element).autocomplete(params());
},
update: function(element, params) {
    $(element).autocomplete("option", "source", params().source);
}
};

var example = example || {};
example.cities = (function ($, jQuery, ko, undefined) {
"use strict";

function ViewModel() {};

ViewModel.prototype.searchCities = function(request, response) 
{
     if (request) 
     {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {q: request.term},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) { response(data); alert('response: ' + data) },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
            });
     }
};    

return { ViewModel: ViewModel };

})($, jQuery, ko);

ko.applyBindings(new example.cities.ViewModel());
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g02ed5rf/10/)

For testing I put the scripts inline and still it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you check, is this because of CORS? else you need to provide more about error details, if you getting 500. check if you able to trap error in server side.

Comment: The service is not my service, but a public service. I cannot seem to get fiddler to work, anyone know how I can see the response? It doesn't go in the error block either so I cannot check the errorThrown...

Answer (score 0):

finally I found it, turns out AdGuard (installed on my pc) blocks cors requests from localhost, makes sense actually